# About some Pythagorean Quadruples

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to find all the Pythagorean Quadruples of the form:
$$
1+(10K+4)^2+(10M+8)^2=(10N+9)^2\qquad K,M,N\in\mathbb{N},M<N
$$

Thank you!

Comment: I would try to find the general solution for all Pythagorean quadruples, and then see how it can be adjusted to create only solutions satisfying your criterion, possibly by setting each solution equal to the form of your corresponding solution, and then solving a system of equations or something.

Comment: I did so,but it didn't work! You may succeed! Thank You!

Comment: Elias,thank You for the addition!

Comment: There is always at least one solution for each $K.$ Below you said "because I have to receive all 10K+4 that cannot be a solution of such an equation." There is nothing to receive. All 10K+4 CAN be a solution of such an equation. See my second answer, below.

Answer (score 7):

There is always a solution for any $K$ in your
$$
1+(10K+4)^2+(10M+8)^2=(10N+9)^2\qquad K,M,N\in\mathbb{N}
$$

given by $$ M= N = 5 K^2 + 4 K   $$

That is
$$ 1 + (10  K + 4)^2  + (50  K^2 + 40 K + 8)^2 =  (50  K^2 + 40 K + 9)^2 =  2500 K^4 + 4000 K^3 + 2500 K^2 + 720 K + 81 $$

Answer (score 6):

All the primitive Pythagorean Quadruples are known. This is Theorem 3 on page 176 and Theorem 4 on page 177 of Jones_Pall_1939.pdf, available at [TERNARY](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/forms.html)  as a pdf. The same information is on the first two pages of Pall_Automorphs_1940.pdf at the same site.

The short version is this: you have an ***odd*** number $$  W = 10 N + 9. $$ Find all quadruples $a,b,c,d$ with $$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = W,  $$ where we are allowed to mix order, take the variables to be positive, negative, or zero. Then all the ***primitive*** quadruples, odd entry first, are given by
$$ \left( a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2 \right)^2 + 4 \left( ad-bc \right)^2 + 4 \left(ac+bd \right)^2 = W^2.   $$
So all quadruples with the odd summand first are
$$ \langle a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2, \; \; 2 \left( ad-bc \right), \; \; 2 \left(ac+bd \right), \; \; W \rangle   $$
You need $$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = W, \; \; a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2 = 1. $$
So, $$ a^2 + b^2 = (W+1)/2,  $$ which is only occasionally possible, and $$ c^2 + d^2 = (W-1)/2,  $$ which is only occasionally possible.

The odd numbers $W$ that allow this, up to 1000, are

```
     1     3     9    17    19    33    35    51    73    81
    99   105   129   145   147   161   163   179   195   201
   233   243   273   289   291   297   339   361   387   393
   451   465   467   483   489   513   521   577   579   585
   611   627   649   675   721   723   739   777   801   809
   819   849   883   899   915   963   969
```

The numbers allowing this, of the form $W = 10N + 9,$ up to 100000, are

```
     9    19    99   129   179   289   339   489   579   649
   739   809   819   849   899   969  1059  1089  1169  1449
  1459  1569  1619  1809  1929  2019  2049  2179  2249  2259
  2449  2499  2739  2769  2889  2979  3329  3369  3489  3529
  3689  3699  3729  4329  4419  4499  4609  4659  4769  4809
  5219  5289  5329  5379  5409  5619  5649  5859  6099  6339
  6409  6499  6569  6659  6729  7059  7219  7299  7329  7539
  7689  7779  7849  7939  8099  8529  8659  8769  8819  8979
  9249  9489  9609  9699  9809 10089 10369 10419 10659 10729
 10819 10889 10899 11049 11139 11169 11379 11539 11699 11809
 11859 12169 12369 12609 12819 12969 13059 13139 13449 13699
 13769 13779 14579 14889 15139 15209 15249 15299 15369 15489
 15859 15939 16019 16179 16209 16289 16419 16489 16649 16659
 16849 16929 17169 17299 17409 17729 17769 18099 18179 18249
 18449 18729 18819 19059 19209 19299 19369 19539 19619 19729
 20169 20289 20339 20499 20739 20809 20969 20979 21059 21219
 21459 21609 21779 21969 22049 22179 22339 22689 22899 22929
 23329 23529 23619 23779 23889 24009 24099 24209 24499 24579
 24659 24819 25089 25289 25449 25539 25779 25809 26019 26099
 26499 26569 26889 27379 27459 27539 27849 28009 28179 28329
 28369 28419 28899 29089 29249 29379 29649 29769 29859 29969
 30259 30369 30609 30849 30979 31059 31139 31299 31689 32169
 32259 32289 32329 32419 32499 32739 32769 32849 33129 33299
 33409 33569 33609 33929 34419 34449 34569 34849 34899 35049
 35299 35379 35409 35459 36099 36129 36369 36489 36649 36969
 37009 37299 37329 37459 37539 37779 37889 38019 38049 38089
 38889 38899 38979 39169 39219 39459 39689 39779 39849 39889
 40179 40329 40499 40899 40969 41059 41129 41219 41289 41379
 41489 41619 41939 42049 42249 42339 42579 42729 43059 43219
 43299 43379 43809 43939 44049 44099 44259 44739 45129 45379
 45609 45699 45729 45969 46099 46209 46259 46569 46659 46819
 46889 47049 47139 47529 47619 47649 47859 47889 48009 48099
 48339 49299 49409 49569 49609 49859 49929 50019 50129 50409
 50419 51009 51049 51209 51219 51849 51939 52129 52419 52489
 52649 52659 52899 53139 53289 53379 53409 53889 54019 54089
 54289 54579 54729 54819 54849 54899 55059 55369 55689 55779
 55809 56019 56179 56339 56449 56499 56529 56609 56899 57129
 57169 57249 57459 57489 57699 58089 58249 58569 58769 59049
 59059 59139 59169 59649 59779 59859 60009 60499 60659 61299
 61329 61449 61539 61649 62289 62409 62499 62529 62659 62729
 62819 63219 63369 63539 63699 63809 64179 64209 64809 64979
 65139 65289 65769 65809 65859 66099 66129 66249 66259 66369
 66579 66819 66889 66979 67049 67139 67699 67779 68049 68129
 68169 68259 68329 68499 68649 68689 69219 69249 69699 69939
 69969 70019 70179 70569 70689 70899 71139 71459 71619 72019
 72609 72649 72739 73059 73449 73619 73729 73889 73929 74049
 74179 74499 74529 74739 74769 75009 75169 75369 75689 75729
 75779 76049 76179 76659 76689 76809 76899 76929 77619 77779
 77889 78249 78409 78499 78579 78729 78929 79209 79539 79569
 79779 79849 80019 80099 80209 80259 80649 80659 80819 80929
 81449 81459 81609 81809 81939 82099 82419 82449 82659 82899
 83529 83619 84339 84579 84609 84819 85299 85409 85699 85859
 86049 86289 86419 86499 86529 86579 86889 86979 87219 87299
 87699 87939 88179 88209 88329 88489 88739 88849 89169 89289
 89619 89729 89889 89929 90249 90339 90739 91089 91459 91529
 91689 91729 91779 92169 92649 92739 92809 92899 92969 92979
 93779 94179 94409 94419 94569 94609 95049 95059 95219 95489
 95529 95649 95779 95939 96099 96849 97379 97449 97489 97779
 97809 98019 98259 98369 98409 98499 98569 98739 98819 98979
 99379 99459 99489 99649
```

Comment: Thanks for the post!How did you get all this numbers,can you give me a formula?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=10K+4,y=10M+8,z=10N+9$ and write your equation as
$$x^2+y^2-z^2=-1.$$
Now the form $x^2+y^2-z^2$ has an automorphism, that is, given it has a certain value for a specific $x,y,z$ it will have the same value provided we define
$$x'=x+2y+2z,\\ y'=2x+y+2z,\\ z'=2x+2y+3z.$$
Your equation holds when $K=M=N=0$ when the triple is $(x,y,z)=(4,8,9)$. Now if we iterate the above substitution, considering things only mod 10, it cycles after six iterations back to $(4,8,9)$, so from one solution to your problem you can get another (typically much larger) solution. The patterns mod 10 for the six iterations are
$$(4,8,9),(8,4,1),(8,2,7),(6,2,1),(2,6,9),(2,8,3),(4,8,9),$$
thereafter repeating every sixth step. When I did this iteration starting at $(4,8,9)$ but not reducing mod 10, I obtained the solution
$$(x,y,z)=(242344,242348,342729).$$
It's clear we can get infinitely many solutions this way, but it is certainly not clear this gets all solutions. A way to get smaller solutions would be nice.

Comment: Thank you! Your idea is good,but I need really all the solutions of this,because I have to receive all 10K+4 that cannot be a solution of such an equation.