# A polynomial in two variables with perfect square values

Tags: polynomials

How can I find for which X and Y the values of the polynomial

$ 100X^2+100Y^2+160X+80Y+81$

are perfect square?

Comment: Also $$(10x)^2+(10y)^2+2\cdot10x\cdot8+2\cdot10y\cdot4+8^2+4^2+1=(10x+8)^2+(10y+4)^2+1$$

Comment: I think we can work modulo 4 here.

Comment: you want every x,y which satisfy your condition, don't you?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ supposed to be integers?

Comment: Yes,X and Y are integers and I am looking for every X and Y,which satisfy this condition.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435980/about-some-pythagorean-quadruples/436044#436044 where (non-complete) parametric solutions are given when the square on the right is taken to be of the form $(10t+9)^2$